# How to install mysql using powershell script?

Tags: mysql, powershell, powershell-3.0

We want to have powershell script for installation of mysql on windows and have public access to mysql.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest installing [chocolaty](https://chocolatey.org/) then you can just run from powershell the command:

```
choco install mysql
```

Or if you are on Powershell version 5.0

```
Find-Package mysql | Install-Package
```